# How to make a combination of a nested list and a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to combine a nested list with another list.

```
a = [['a_1','b_2','c_3'],['a_3','b_4','c_5']]
b = ['d_1','d_2']
```

The goal is to append each element of list b to each sublist of list a.

```
c = [['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_1'], ['a_3', 'b_4', 'c_5', 'd_1'], ['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_2'], ['a_3', 'b_4', 'c_5','d_2']]
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you wrote in attempt to solve this problem. We will try to help you fix it :)

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [['a_1','b_2','c_3'],['a_3','b_4','c_5']]
b = ['d_1','d_2']

out = [[*l2, l1] for l1 in b for l2 in a]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_1'], ['a_3', 'b_4', 'c_5', 'd_1'], ['a_1', 'b_2', 'c_3', 'd_2'], ['a_3', 'b_4', 'c_5', 'd_2']]
```

Comment: This is simple and great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I agree. This answer should be accepted as the best for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[0].append(b[0])
a[1].append(b[1])
```

Or for many lists in `a`:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i].append(b[i])
```

Comment: Use indent in 'for loop', I typed but it auto corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the first list and append the members of the second list to the members of the first. You can try this code,

```
c=[]
for i in b:
    for j in a:
        j.append(i)
        c.append(j)
```